# ListView causes whitescreen below Appbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have a function that returns a Widget into my builder.

I want it to return a ListView, but everything below the Appbar just gets white with this piece of code in my return:

```
@override
  Widget details(BuildContext context) {
    var cell = (Widget widget) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: widget,
    );

    var locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

    return ListView( 
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text("Test")),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The calling builder has this as body:

```
return Container(
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 161, 181, 0.4),
              child:
                Hero(
                  tag: collectible.heroTag,
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 250,
                    child: FadeInImage(
                      image: collectible.detailImage,
                      placeholder: collectible.icon,
                      fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      fadeOutDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      fadeInCurve: Curves.linear,
                      fadeOutCurve: Curves.linear,
                      // errorBuilder: (context, obj, satckTrace) =>
                        // Image.asset('images/bildfehlt.png'),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  ),
                ),

              ),
              CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text("Got it"),
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                value: collectible.isObtained(settings),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  collectible.setObtained(settings, value);
                },
              ),
              collectible.details(context), // <-------- function
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Did I implement sth wrong?
Any other widget, Container or Column for Example just work fine.

Error-Log:
https://pastebin.com/geSBXcB6

Comment: Try giving the first ```Container``` of your ```Column``` a height. :) @Salatgurke

Comment: why you override details method? can you also add class which contains details method?'

Comment: giving the container a height didnt change anything sadly

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I don't really think that I need this override. It was just there from previous coding.

Comment: @Salatgurke can you try setting "shrinkWrap: true," for the ListView?

Comment: That didn't change anything. But I found and posted my errorlog

Comment: Make sure that everything in the column has a fixed height. i.e. the container and CheckboxListTile has a fixed height. Then add "crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min," to the column.

Comment: I can only set the height for the Container containing the image and this doesn't change anything in the result

Comment: Try wrapping the list view with a expanded widget

Comment: I wrapped it, but the area below the Appbar still stays white